# Wildfly in Docker container not starting

Tags: java, docker, jboss, wildfly, devops

I'm trying to access the welcome page of Wildfly running on a Docker container in Windows 10 Pro. This is what I did:

Pulled the image:

```
docker pull jboss/wildfly
```

Run Wildfly container (this works fine, in the Wildfly log I can see it started correctly):

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly
```

Find the container ID:

```
docker ps
```

Inspect the IP address:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" cac63ed21d78
```

The IP address is `172.17.0.2`, in a browser I go to http://172.17.0.2:8080/ but the browser hangs and times out. What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I also tried with `127.0.0.1:8080` and it's not working either

**UPDATE2**

Console log:

```
docker --version

#Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a

docker run hello-world

#Hello from Docker!

docker run --detach --publish 8080:80 --name webserver nginx

#Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
#latest: Pulling from library/nginx
#8ec398bc0356: Pull complete
#465560073b6f: Pull complete
#f473f9fd0a8c: Pull complete
#Digest:  sha256:b2d89d0a210398b4d1120b3e3a7672c16a4ba09c2c4a0395f18b9f7999b768f2
#Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
#c5cdb6de11240b5fe33bc424779721e1b44948797fd6ff389004d0766b71dd17

docker ps

#CONTAINER ID IMAGE COMMAND CREATED STATUS PORTS NAMES c5cdb6de1124 
#nginx "nginx -g 'daemon of" 10 minutes ago Up 10 minutes 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp webserver
```

Comment: See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43762751/7873775 and try 10.0.75.1:8080 and 10.0.75.2:8080.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't work. I have both docker and the browser running on the same Windows 10 machine.Isn't `10.0.75.x` an external address and the browser tries to find it on the web?

Comment: OK, let's try to find the problem. Please post the results of the following CLI commands: 1. `docker --version`, 2. `docker run hello-world`, 3. 
`docker run --detach --publish 8080:80 --name webserver nginx`, 4. then try to open http://localhost:8080

Comment: Please see question updated with the console log. I tried `localhost:8080` and it times out. `docker ps` shows `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED     STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
c5cdb6de1124        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of"   10 minutes ago
    Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   webserver`

Comment: @Evgeniy Khyst  I found [this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/) that talks about docker networking. It says that the server running inside the container has to listen to all the interfaces (the last part of the article), does this apply?

Comment: could you please try with http://localhost:8080/ , the IP address does not work for me too, only works with localhost ....

Comment: @LinPy No, localhost never worked, you are saying that it works for you accessing a Wildfly container  from Windows?

Comment: What is the `docker run` command you are using?

Comment: docker run -it -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly

Comment: Thanks, for whatever reason it doesn't work for me, do you have in Windows a `nat network`  (the default network for containers running on Windows) ?

Comment: Your `docker run` command also works for me on my windows 10 machine. On network, I can see a virtual `DockerNAT` adapter.

Comment: you could try to bind the wildfly daemon to all ip addresses inside the container, using the following command 
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 -it jboss/wildfly /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -bmanagement=0.0.0.0 -b 0.0.0.0

Comment: in your second update, you do start an nginx on port 8080 in your container environment. is this working then?

Comment: What does `docker ps` show in column `PORTS` for the running Wildfly container? Does it work if you run the container without explicit port mapping just as `docker run -it jboss/wildfly`?

Comment: What IP address does 'docker-machine ip default' return ?  it should be the one you use if localhost doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you create a container, it does not publish any of its ports to the outside world. Network 172.17.X.X is internal. If you need to bind IP address to host ip run docker container with -p flag, like that:

-p 8080:8080

> Map TCP port 8080 in the container to port 8080 on the Docker host

Comment: Why does [this example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/docker/getting-started-with-docker-and-wildfly) work if the ports are not published to the outside world?

Comment: @Will you incorrectly edited the response, if you take a look at the question it is exactly what I was doing.

Comment: @ps0604 sounds like there is a network problem. In your case check firewall rules

Comment: My answer is correct, because it's based on documentation recomendation.

Comment: Ivan, what is the difference between your answer and the setup I describe in the question?

Answer (score 3):

From: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/

> Port forwarding works for localhost; --publish, -p, or -P all work. Ports exposed from Linux are forwarded to the host.

So it should be accessible from http://localhost:8080

---

If that doesn't work, then try the windows example

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

Which should be accessible http://localhost:80

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/index#explore-the-application-and-run-examples

---

If even that fails try:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

And use http://[docker-machine-ip]:80

Comment: Could you try the example I posted above to see if its a problem with jboss/wildfly or if its your windows networking?

Comment: And if nginx doesn't work then you can run

 'docker-machine ip default'

And try use the IP there instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

The key information is `Docker container in Windows 10 Pro` - this is very generic specification how your Docker on Windows works. There can be many options e.g. `Docker for Windows` with/without `Linux containers`, `Docker toolbox`, remote instance, ....

Generally Docker containers on Windows are running in some kind of virtual machine (Hyper-V, Virtualbox, ...), usually. So there is additional network layer, which may not be accessible directly from your Windows network namespace. But [linked example](http://www.mastertheboss.com/soa-cloud/docker/getting-started-with-docker-and-wildfly) runs on Linux machine, where this additional network layer doesn't exist. And that is a reason why copy/pasted Linux example doesn't work on Windows. So run container as usual and expose port 8080:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 jboss/wildfly
```

But IP for access will be different and container IP can't be used, because that internal docker network is very likely not accessible from Windows. Rather try to use IP of your Windows OS. Eventually check documentation of used `Docker on Windows` solution and find which IP is used for exposed ports.

If you have advance windows/linux networking skills, then you may somehow route/forward port from container network namespace, through intermediate VM network layer to Windows network layer. But it can be pretty complicated.

Comment: Jan, I installed [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows), downloaded the image and run the Wildfly container as explained in the tutorial above. In the console I see that it starts fine, and the `8080:8080` it's what in theory should work, but it does not. I don't know about networking, where should I start looking?

Comment: @ps0604 If you want to follow Linux tutorial blindly, then use Linux. As I mentioned doc is your friend - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/ there is explicitly mentioned `There is no docker0 bridge on Windows: Because of the way networking is implemented in Docker Desktop for Windows, you cannot see a docker0 interface on the host. This interface is actually within the virtual machine.`. Please deal with that limitation.

Answer (score 0):

I had a peer working on a windows system that faced the same issue. He put a lot of effort into it and just couldn't get anywhere. There's a lot of weird stuff that happens with Docker Desktop for windows it seems. We finally just installed the linux subsystem for windows and installed docker on there and it worked like a charm for him from then on. If you wish to stick to windows and you don't mind working on the linux subsystem, I suggest you go down that route. We went further than what Jan Garaj suggested and just found it to be a waste of time. Docker Desktop for Windows is meant to be a env where you completely work within it - using dev containers etc. Host-Container stuff is a pain with it.

Comment: Yes, I agree, I will create the containers in Ubuntu instead of Windows, I have no problems there. The only thing is that I develop in Windows, so I would have to test three times, once in windows while developing, then in the linux container, and finally when I upload the container to the cloud. If I can run the container in Windows, then I would test only twice.

Comment: which is why I suggested the linux subsystem.. you don't actually have to change context 3 times,, maybe 2-2.5 times ;)