# Connect locally to a docker postgres db

Tags: docker

I have been trying to connect from Windows to a docker postgres database without succes.
On windows i am running docker over wld (ubuntu).
Using the following command i have been created container for DB

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name local-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass1234 postgres
```

On local host (Windows) i have been installed PgAdmin 4, which i want to connect with my docker postgres db.

Inspecting the container created using the following command i noticed that the IP is private 172.17.0.3

```
docker inspect local-postgres
```

Using PgAdmin 4 i wasn't able to connect to previous IP.

Can you help me understand why?

Thank you in advance.

I tried to map the port 5432 with 5432 without succes.

Comment: Does this (and dozens of similar posts) answer your question? [Docker on Windows: how to connect to container from host using container IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41400043/docker-on-windows-how-to-connect-to-container-from-host-using-container-ip)

Answer (score 0):

You're already binding your host machine's port to the container.

So you should be able to access your Postgres instance with localhost:5432